# How to change a SSH host key?

Tags: debian, ssh-keys, fingerprint

I cloned a server and so they've the same RSA key fingerprint.

It seems to be defined in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`.

What is the correct way to change that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Follow these steps to regenerate OpenSSH Host Keys

1. Delete old ssh host keys: `rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*`
2. Reconfigure OpenSSH Server: `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`
3. Update all ssh client(s) `~/.ssh/known_hosts` files

[Reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-regenerate-openssh-host-keys/)

Answer (score 80):

Or, remove keys and

```
ssh-keygen -A
```

Explanation:

`-A`: For each of the key types (rsa1, rsa, dsa, ecdsa and ed25519) for which host keys do not exist, generate the host keys with the default key file path, an empty passphrase, default bits for the key type, and default comment. This is used by /etc/rc to generate new host keys.

Comment: The OP's tags specify debian, but being non platform specific, this answer seems like the better solution.

Comment: Hmm, except it doesn't seem to work for older versions.  Eg fails on debian squeeze, which has OpenSSH_5.5p1

Comment: For your information (from http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ssh-keygen/) `ssh-keygen -A`does the following: "For each of the key types (rsa1, rsa, dsa, ecdsa and ed25519) for which host keys do not exist, generate the host keys with the default key file path, an empty passphrase, default bits for the key type, and default comment. This is used by /etc/rc to generate new host keys."

Answer (score 31):

For a generic method of doing this:

`ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key`

`ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -b 4096 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`

`ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key`

`ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ed25519 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key`

mix and match according to the keys your version of OpenSSH supports. Current implementations commonly generate only rsa, ecdsa & ed25519.

Do note that that the `-b` argument can be used in (most) cases to specify key size.

You should pick a key-size appropriate for the intended lifetime of the key and the amount of time you find acceptable to open a connection as the impact will be more pronounced on slower hardware. For example, using the default RSA key size (2048 at the time of writing) is absolutely fine (again, as of the time of writing) if you're rolling the key over periodically.

Comment: I think one way to improve this question would be to add the way to increase the number of bits. i.e. `ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -b 4096 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`

Comment: `ecdsa` default is 256. Use `ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ecdsa -b 521 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key` to get the biggest key. Yes 521 not 512.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Using larger keys is not free. You are usually better off rolling keys over periodically rather than simply picking the largest size possible and paying the computation costs since, even a 2048bit RSA key is best attacked by trying to obtain it rather than trying to factorise it.

Comment: Best answer for repairing remote server like centos 6x via anaconda

Comment: This has worked for me for centos 7 vm.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using RHEL, CentOS or Fedora, then you can simply delete them and restart the SSHd service. They will be regenerated.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. `/etc/init.d/ssh restart<newline>
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key<newline>
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key<newline>
[....] Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshdCould not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key<newline>
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key`

Comment: Indeed. Only works on RHEL based distribs. Sorry

Comment: Good advice, thanks. It worked for me on CentOS installation.

Comment: Definitely works on Fedora

Comment: FYI, this approach works on Alpine Linux v 3.13.2   What I did was `rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*` then `reboot`. I bet you could just bounce the ssh service, but I didn't try that.

Comment: Be careful with RHEL 8.7 and `cloud-init` - the behavior changed. For more details see - https://serverfault.com/questions/1116547/why-the-rhel8-system-do-not-generate-ssh-host-keys-automatically-when-missing

Comment: Works on Void Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Debian 10.7 user here.
Mixing the two best answer was the cleanest way to solde the problem :

( As root or sudo it yourself )

- server A.B.C.D : Mooving old keys in a "backup" folder

  `mkdir -p ~/ssh_backup && mv /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* ~/ssh_backup/.`
- server A.B.C.D : Generate new keys :

  `ssh-keygen -A`
- CLIENT SIDE : forger about the previous key for server A.B.C.D

  `ssh-keygen -R A.B.C.D`

Here you go, the fresh ssh keys can be used.

Comment: Also works on Arch

Answer (score 1):

Script (in case restarting the sshd daemon does not automatically regenerate the keys)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Regenerate SSHD key materials, restart sshd if "-r" passed on command line

set -o nounset

WHERE=/etc/ssh

# go to directory

pushd $WHERE >/dev/null

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
   echo "Could not cd to $WHERE -- exiting" >&2
   exit 1
fi

# create backup folder

NOW=`date '+%Y%m%d.%H%M%S'` # default NOW string
BAKDIR=bak_$NOW

mkdir $BAKDIR

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
   echo "Could not mkdir $BAKDIR -- exiting" >&2
   exit 1
fi

# move existing key material to backup folder

mv ssh_host_* $BAKDIR

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
   echo "Could not move old files to $BAKDIR -- exiting" >&2
   exit 1
fi

# generate new keys

ssh-keygen -A

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
   echo "Could not recreate keys -- exiting" >&2
   exit 1
fi

# ssh-keygen may create DSA keys but:
# "Never use DSA or ECDSA"
# https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46781/25661

/bin/rm -f *_dsa_key *_dsa_key.pub
/bin/rm -f *_ecdsa_key *_ecdsa_key.pub

# on Fedora, one has to tune permissions a bit

chmod 640 *_key
chgrp ssh_keys *_key

# make sure SELinux attributes are as they should be

restorecon -R $WHERE

# Done

echo "New key material"
ls -l *_key *_key.pub

# Do the risky thing

if [[ $1 == '-r' ]]; then
   echo "Restarting SSH daemon"
   systemctl restart sshd
fi

# go back to where you where

popd >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

On AWS Linux & thus likely other Red Hat derivatives, the result from restarting sshd and using `ssh-keygen -A` are not the same.

You get different keys and different group ownership. Restarting sshd with the keys deleted gives the same outcome as the initial installation.

Initial conditions:

```bash
ls -l /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*   
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys  227 Dec  7  2017 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      162 Dec  7  2017 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys  387 Dec  7  2017 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       82 Dec  7  2017 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys 1679 Dec  7  2017 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      382 Dec  7  2017 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Use `ssh-keygen -A` to create the host keys:

```bash
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
ssh-keygen -A

-rw-------. 1 root root  668 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  628 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------. 1 root root  227 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  200 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------. 1 root root  444 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  120 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------. 1 root root 1003 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  668 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub
-rw-------. 1 root root 1679 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  420 Oct 25 13:30 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Let sshd generate the missing host keys:

```bash
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
systemctl restart sshd

-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys  227 Oct 25 13:31 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      162 Oct 25 13:31 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys  387 Oct 25 13:31 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       82 Oct 25 13:31 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys 1675 Oct 25 13:31 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      382 Oct 25 13:31 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `shred` (or `gshred` on macOS/`brew install coreutils`).

```
sudo shred -u /etc/ssh/*_key /etc/ssh/*_key.pub
```