# Why the RHEL8 system do not generate SSH host keys automatically when missing?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, cloud-init, rhel8

On the RHEL 8 and previous it is usual, that the SSH host keys in `/etc/ssh` are generated automatically by `sshd` service when missing. Usually there should be:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Restart of the node or even `systemctl restart sshd` should be sufficient.

But as of the minor version RHEL 8.7 this may not work any more and the `sshd` crashes complaining about missing host keys in the journal log. Why? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sshd` service by default calls `sshd-keygen.target`, which checks availability of host keys in `/etc/ssh` directory and generates it when missing.

However this well known functionality can be blocked by the new version of `cloud-init`. As of `cloud-init-22.1-5.el8.noarch` there is new file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/sshd-keygen@.service.d/disable-sshd-keygen-if-cloud-init-active.conf
```

with content:

```
# In some cloud-init enabled images the sshd-keygen template service may race
# with cloud-init during boot causing issues with host key generation.  This
# drop-in config adds a condition to sshd-keygen@.service if it exists and
# prevents the sshd-keygen units from running *if* cloud-init is going to run.
#
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=!/run/systemd/generator.early/multi-user.target.wants/cloud-init.target
```

So when you use the `cloud-init` you have 2 options now:

1. Generate host keys manually with `ssh-keygen -A` (see [How to change a SSH host key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/471327/how-to-change-a-ssh-host-key) for more details and options.
2. Comment the condition

Simply put the `#` sign before `ConditionPathExists...`

```
[Unit]
#ConditionPathExists=!/run/systemd/generator.early/multi-user.target.wants/cloud-init.target
```

Then reload the systemd configuration with `systemctl daemon-reload`. The usual behavior should be working again.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using cloud-init, then you can fix it by adding 'ssh' module in cloud-init config file in section "cloud_init_modules". Refer [cloud-init docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/configuring_and_managing_cloud-init_for_rhel_8/index)

This will generate ssh host key during the firstboot.

You can test this in instance where you are having issue:

```
cloud-init config file: /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
Check if you have 'ssh' module in "cloud_init_modules" section
Run this command to verify cloud-init action. NOTE: This will REBOOT your instance and run the cloud-init action from the scratch.
# cloud-init clean --reboot
```

Verify the ssh host key in /etc/ssh/ directory and sshd service status.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting ssh key types in cloud.cfg

```
resize_rootfs_tmp: /dev
ssh_deletekeys:   1
ssh_genkeytypes: ['rsa', 'ecdsa', 'ed25519']
```